# React Native - Passing param to sibling of custom navigator component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have custom navigator as shown below

```
const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    List: ListScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        }
    });

export default class CustomHomeStack extends React.Component {
    static router = HomeStackNavigator.router;
    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;

        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }}>
                <CustomHomeHeader /* breadCrumbParam={??} */ />
                <HomeStackNavigator navigation={navigation} />
            </SafeAreaView >
        );
    }
}
```

When navigating to List or Details, I can pass a param to next screen `this.props.navigation.navigate('List', { breadCrumbParam: {id: theId, displayName: theName }} })`

I also need to pass the same params to `CustomHomeHeader`. (similar to passing a param to the parent/sibling component via props). Is this possible?

Comment: it's a bit unclear. like exactly what you want to do, pass data as props to customehomeheader or something else?

Comment: Yes. Pass data as props to `CustomHomeHeader` from HomeScreen, ListScreen, and DetailsScreen

Comment: so as you did in the above   `<CustomHomeHeader /* breadCrumbParam={??} */ /> `. , is there any problem there.

Comment: No. I need to pass breadCrumbParam to CustomHeader but, don't know how to get it from HomeScreen to CustomHomeStack

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you need to do few changes ,
1. add CustomHomeStack in the navigation stack
2.pass data from home to homestack
3.recieve data from home in homestack and pass as props to CustomHomeHeader

so the below code will be

```
const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    List: ListScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
    CustomHomeStack:CustomHomeStack
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        }
    });
```

then in home  suppose you want to call homestack on button clikc,

```
class Home extends Component{


onButtonClick(){
this.props.navigation.push('CustomHomeStack', { breadCrumbParam: 100 })

}


}
```

then in customhomestack you need to consume the navigation params and pass it to customgheader by storing in state.:

```
class CustomHomeStack extends Component {

 constructor(props){
        super(props);
this.state={
breadCrumbId:''
}
    }

componentDidMount(){
let breadCrumb = this.props.navigation.getParam("breadCrumbParam", "NO-ID");
this.setState({breadCrumbId:breadCrumb})
}

 render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;

        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }}>
                <CustomHomeHeader  breadCrumbParam={this.state.breadCrumbId}  />
                <HomeStackNavigator navigation={navigation} />
            </SafeAreaView >
        );
    }


}
```

Hope it helps. otherwise post the issue